# Submitting a form with GET method which doesn't match route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to filter results by category and I'd like to use the GET method instead of POST. However, I am doing something wrong that I can't figure out: the form's action does not match the defined route, so it triggers a different method.

Here's the form:

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag '/expenses/search', method: 'get' do %>
    <%= select_tag 'category_name', options_from_collection_for_select(Category.order(:name), :name, :name) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'search' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Sending this form produces an URL like the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/expenses/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&category_name=Alcohol&commit=Search
```

However the route is defined like this:

```
resources :expenses
get 'expenses/search/:category_name', to: 'gastos#search_by_category'
```

This means the URL where the form is submitted isn't the one I'm trying to submit it to. It's matched with the one corresponding to the `show` method, as you can imagine.

How can I submit the form to the matching URL? What is the usual way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set your route properly as it has unrecognized `:category_name` segment. Your route should be defined like this:

```
get 'expenses/search', to: 'gastos#search_by_category`
```

Answer (score 0):

If your route is nested on expenses I recommend to use block function

```
resources :expenses do
    collection do
        match 'search', to: 'gastos#search_by_category`, via: :get
    end
end
```

Is a good practice to use rials routes helper, try to avoid put routes with plain text, in your case will be:

```
<%= form_tag search_expenses_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <%= select_tag 'category_name', options_from_collection_for_select(Category.order(:name), :name, :name) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'search' %>
  <% end %>
```

Furthermore, don't confuse 'query params' with 'url params'

http//www.host.com/profile/12?type='json'

In this example '12' is a url param and is expresed with :(nameofparam) in routes files but 'type' is a query param that are not expresed on rails routes.

Comment: `match` is getting deprecated. Using `get` is recommended.

Comment: this doesn't work either. I figured out that the problem is that if the search route is declared after the resource (or the way you propose) it is then overriden by the route corresponding to show

Comment: I made a mistake, try with collection

Comment: This method must work, if not put the error here please or what you are getting

Comment: please explain that way of definining routes with blocks and what is `collection` for. Also you should mention what I said before as another solution

Answer (score 0):

#### It's supposed to work like that, since it's client-side.

You see, parameters are sent by the browser, that (in general) has no understanding of how your site routing works inside. Submitting a form, in general, requires an URL (to submit params to) and a set of parameters, which in case with **GET** *typically*<sup>*</sup> gets passed as a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

The browser will eventually hit the exact route that is specified in form's URL and supply all the form's parameters in a *query string* appended to the end in usual format:

```
...?category=stuff
```

You simply cannot expect the browser to hit a different route (which *query string* is not part of) with one form just because it has a different value in one of the `<input>`s.

<sup>*</sup> *I've never actually seen this done differently, but I didn't find a firm requirement of this either.*

#### Do you really want pretty search links that badly?

You could try to circumvent this by placing a "prettifying redirection" – direct search queries to that action, but do not perform search there: instead use the received parameters to construct a route and redirect your user to it.

```
def search_redirect
  redirect_to whatever_search_path(category: params[:category])
end
```

That would trigger the route helper to build the pretty adress that conforms to the defined routes.

#### Too hacky?

Well, you could go with submitting a form through JavaScript and alter the parameters and URL request in any way you want. But this is still hacky and I wouldn't do either. Query string in search requests looks perfectly fine to me.